# 400 Bad Request received after posting request

Tags: http, post

When I send the following http post request:

```
POST /query.fcgi HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 63

form_state=3&form_name=system_sw_upgrade&field_name=http_upload
```

The server responds with a BAD Request

What's wrong with the request?

Comment: It seems it is missing controller (or) request processor in the URL, last line your post seesm only parameters. Here is link on causes and solutions. http://www.getnetgoing.com/HTTP-400.html

Answer (score 2):

Your request is missing a `Host` header.  From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (see 14.23):

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field.